# disable/hide UISearchBar when datasource is nil

Tags: hide, uisearchbar, swift4

I want to make sure that no search bar is displayed when the datasource of my table view is empty. (Makes sense, no? shouldn't that be default behaviour?)

Here's a piece of my code that tries (currently uncommented) different things to accomplish that, but somehow it doesn't work.

Can anybody advise me what I'm doing wrong? Let me know if you need more snippets.

```
messagesArray=loadMessages()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if (self.messagesArray.count==0){
                self.noMessageview.isHidden=false
                //self.searchController.searchBar.isHidden = true
                //self.searchController.isActive = false
            } else{
                self.noMessageview.isHidden=true
                //self.searchController.searchBar.isHidden = false
                //self.searchController.isActive = true
            }


            self.spinner.stopAnimating()
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

I declare the search controller like this:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

and in the ViewDidLoad I do:

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Comment: How did you add the searchController, can you please explain more about it  and update your question, is it added to the table view header or the navigation bar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using iOS 11 because of setting `UISearchController` from `navigationItem`, Thus you can use the following code to remove it:

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never;
        self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
    };
```

I had some problem and i think its iOS 11 bug, when removing the `UISearchController`, the view doesn't get adjusted thus i had to call this right before removing `UISearchController`.

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never;
```

Thats all.